# how to connect api django 1.10 with c#

Tags: c#, django, django-views, c#-3.0

I'm trying to connect Django API with c # but when I connect I face a problem in C#.

Django here I use as a server API and C# as a client.
Errors in C# are "CSRF is missing or incorrect".

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        private static string json;

        public static string url { get; private set; }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            /*

               try
               {

                   CookieContainer container = new CookieContainer();
                   HttpWebRequest request1 = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://127.0.0.1/api/");
                   request1.Proxy = null;
                   request1.CookieContainer = container;
                   using (HttpWebResponse response1 = (HttpWebResponse)request1.GetResponse())
                   {
                       foreach (Cookie cookie1 in response1.Cookies)
                       {

                           //Console.WriteLine(response.IsSuccessStatusCode);
                           var csrf = cookie1.Value;
                           Console.WriteLine(csrf);
                           Console.WriteLine("name=" + cookie1.Name);
                           Console.WriteLine();
                           Console.Write((int)response1.StatusCode);
                           //PostRespone("http://localhost/api/multiplyfunction/");

                       }

                   }

               }

               catch (WebException e)
               {
                   Console.WriteLine(e.Status);
               }
               /*  HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost/api/");
                 request.CookieContainer = Cookie; // use the global cookie variable
                 string postData = "100";
                 byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
                 request.Method = "POST";
                 request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8";
                 request.ContentLength = data.Length;

                 using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream())
                 {
                     stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                 }

                 WebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                 string responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();*/
            WebClient csrfmiddlewaretoken = new WebClient();


            CookieContainer cookieJar = new CookieContainer();

           var request1 = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://localhost/api/");
            request1.CookieContainer = cookieJar;

            var response1 = request1.GetResponse();

            string baseSiteString = csrfmiddlewaretoken.DownloadString("http://localhost/api/");
            //    string csrfToken = Regex.Match(baseSiteString, "<meta name=\"csrf-token\" content=\"(.*?)\" />").Groups[1].Value;

            // wc.Headers.Add("X-CSRF-Token", csrfToken);
            csrfmiddlewaretoken.Headers.Add("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
            using (HttpWebResponse response2 = (HttpWebResponse)request1.GetResponse())
            {
                foreach (Cookie cookie1 in response2.Cookies)
                {
                    //string cookie = csrfmiddlewaretoken.ResponseHeaders[HttpResponseHeader.SetCookie];//(response as HttpWebResponse).Headers[HttpResponseHeader.SetCookie];
                    Console.WriteLine(baseSiteString);
                    //Console.WriteLine("CSRF Token: {0}", csrfToken);
                    //Console.WriteLine("Cookie: {0}", cookie);
//


                    csrfmiddlewaretoken.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType, "application/json; charset=utf-8");
                    //wc.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Accept, "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01");
                    var csrf1 = cookie1.Value;
                    string ARG1 = ("100");
                    string ARG2 = ("5");
                    string ARG = ("ARG");
                    string csrfmiddlewaretoken1 =cookie1.Name +"="+cookie1.Value;
                    csrfmiddlewaretoken.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie, csrfmiddlewaretoken1);
                    //string csrf = string.Join(cookie, ARG1, ARG2);

                    //string dataString =cookie;
                    // string dataString = @"{""user"":{""email"":"""+uEmail+@""",""password"":"""+uPassword+@"""}}";
                    string dataString = "{\"ARG1\": \"100\", \"ARG2\": \"5\"}";
                  //  string dataString = "csrftokenmiddlewaretoken="+csrfmiddlewaretoken;
                    //dataString += "&ARG1=10";
                    //dataString += "&ARG2=10";
                    byte[] dataBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(dataString);
                    //byte[] respon2 = csrfmiddlewaretoken.DownloadData(new Uri("http://localhost/api/statusfunction/"));
                    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://localhost/api/statusfunction/?ARG");

                    // Get the response.
                    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

                    // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
                    Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                    // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
                    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
                    // Read the content.
                    string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    // Display the content.
                    Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer);


                    byte[] responseBytes = csrfmiddlewaretoken.UploadData(new Uri("http://localhost/api/multiplyfunction/"), "POST", dataBytes);
                    string responseString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responseBytes);
                   Console.WriteLine(responseString);
                    //  byte[] res = csrfmiddlewaretoken.UploadFile("http://localhost/api/multiplyfunction/", @"ARG1:100");


                   // Console.WriteLine(result);

                    Console.WriteLine("value=" + cookie1.Value);
                    Console.WriteLine("name=" + cookie1.Name);
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.Write((int)response2.StatusCode);
                    // PostRespone("http://localhost/api/multiplyfunction/");

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well then you need to supply the csrf token. This has nothing to do with c#,

Comment: The following code that I have made in python:

Answer (score 0):

Do you accept POST requests in your Django view? If yes, you should use @csrf_exempt decorator for the view that handles POST requests. The other option is to provide CSRF token from C# side.